# Scraping multiple urls using urllib in Python/Anaconda (For Loop issue)

Tags: python, anaconda

1st time poster here, so please be gentle!  I am very new to Python and am having a little trouble scraping multiple urls using the following code:

```
    from urllib import urlopen as uReq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    my_url = ["https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/birmingham/?q=birmingham&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home&page_size=100", "https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/birmingham/?identifier=birmingham&page_size=100&q=birmingham&search_source=home&radius=0&pn=2"]



for urls in my_url:


uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()


page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")


containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"listing-results-wrapper"})

filename = "links.csv"
f = open (filename, "w")

headers = "link\n"

f.write(headers)


for container in containers:
    link =  container.div.div.a["href"]

    print("link: " + link)

    f.write(link + "\n")

   f.close()
```

I am guessing that I am making a very elemental mistake, but I can't seem to find anything by searching the forum/google etc as I must be looking in the wrong places.

Edit:  It has occurred to me that I would be best served to explain what I am trying to achieve!  I am attempting to create a single csv file containing the information grabbed by the variable 'containers'.

This code seems to work well for just 1 url, but I am getting AttributeError: 'list object has no attribute 'strip' when adding additional urls.

Would anybody be kind enough to offer some assistance please?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's difficult to tell from how your code is formatted, but is the `f.close() inside the final `for` loop, or outside? If it is inside than you are closing the file after only a single `write`.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, everything got a little out of line when I copied across into the question.  I believe the f.close() is inside the final for loop.

Comment: The code keeps returning an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Well could that be your bug? you are closing file `f` before you write all the links to it. You should pull this out of the loop if I understand your logic correctly

Comment: If you are getting any errors, you should update the question to reflect this (and maybe point to what line is returning the error if you know)

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to this!  I think I may add a new question showing the existing, working code for single url scrapes, to see if people can suggest a way to tailor that to scrape multiple, as this seems to be where my issue lies

Answer (score 0):

The code is messed up, but the list is being called.

```
from urllib import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = ["https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/birmingham/?q=birmingham&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home&page_size=100", "https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/birmingham/?identifier=birmingham&page_size=100&q=birmingham&search_source=home&radius=0&pn=2"]



for urls in my_url:
    uClient = uReq(urls)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"listing-results-wrapper"})
    filename = "links.csv"
    f = open (filename, "w")
    headers = "link\n"
    f.write(headers)
    for container in containers:
        link =  container.div.div.a["href"]
        print("link: " + link)
        f.write(link + "\n")
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I no longer get an error message with this code!  The only remaining issue is that this seems only to save the information from the 2nd (final) url in the list (or final url).  Could this be due to the order of the code?

Comment: You should wrap the for loop in a with open-statement or change the open-method to "a". Otherwise your overwriting content at each url in the loop.